# php sql linking together primary and foreign keys (linked lists)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linked-list

So here's the desired thing i'd like to do. I have two tables in sql 
I'd like to echo out all the messages and the username of the message sender.

here's how the tables are set up.

```
table name: user   
user_id user_name
   1       abc
   2       bob  
   3       pqr


table2 name : message
intro_id       user_id        msg
    1              4          abc
    2              4          jkl 
    3              2          cbd
```

desired output would be like this

new abc

new jkl

bob  cbd

My code so far only outputs the messages

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  $row['msg']  ;
  }
```

Comment: While this question i'm sure has been answered a million times +1 for tables visuals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query to obtain the user_name

```
mysql_query("SELECT user.user_name, message.msg FROM message INNER JOIN user ON message.user_id = user.user_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo  $row['user_name'] . ": " . $row['msg']  ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if your method or the other answer from CoBolt is more efficient? if so please explain!

Comment: it is absolutely equivalent, I gave you the standard way to write joins, please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join and be aware of index on `message.user_id`, it will improve performance when you'll get a lot of records inside `message`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user.user_name,message.msg FROM user,message WHERE user.user_id=message.user_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  $row['user_name']." ".$row['msg'];
  }
```

This should work.

Please comment if it doesnt